# GA - Tracking embedded web browser (3rd party) visitors - ie. Pandora, 1password

Tags: cross-browser, google-analytics

We have a media buy with Pandora. For mobile users,(once clicked on banner), they are directed to our site inside of the pandora app. There app does not accept GA cookies. Does anyone have any work arounds for tracking 3rd party in-app visitors?  We are currently using UTM urls for inbound clicks, so we see initial "land", but nothing more than that.

We are considering creating a duplicate of our site and dedicate it to pandora visitors. This will give us aggregate numbers, but not sessions.

Thanks,
Udi

Answer (score 0):

Mobile applications such as Pandora, Facebook, Twitter etc do not pass referrer information.

There are many articles around this if you search on Google, such as: http://searchengineland.com/rip-referrer-data-how-mobile-apps-can-kill-your-mobile-metrics-79982

All visitors from mobile applications will appear in the 'Direct' section of GA.

As you mention, the use of unique UTM click url will at the very least allow you to see where the user has come from.

Be aware of the discrepancies you will see between click 'redirects' from an accredited ad server such as DFP and GA 'visits' two very different methodologies.